# How can i properly append this in jquery

Tags: jquery

I have this code, im appending table inside a div with an id of "printWayBill" within a loop. Each row get its values from variable inside the loop. But my problem is this code is not appending all tr and td inside table. How can i properly select the last element inside the div inside the table element so i can properly append all tr and td?

Look at this screenshot: http://prntscr.com/mxnk9m

I hope someone could help me. Thanks!

```
var j=1;
        $('#table_1').find('tr').each(function (i, el) {
        var $tds = $(this).find('td');
    if (i > 2) {

        var lfrom = $tds.eq(5).text();
        var lfaddress = "address address address";
        var lfcontactno = "0000000";
        var lto = $tds.eq(10).text();
        var ltaddress = $tds.eq(16).text();
        var lbrgy = $tds.eq(17).text();
        var lcity = $tds.eq(18).text();
        var lprovince = $tds.eq(19).text();
        var ltcontactno = $tds.eq(21).text();
        var lproduct = $tds.eq(11).text();
        var lprice = $tds.eq(15).text();

        var ntable_o= "<table id='printWayBillTable" + j + "'"  +  " style='width: 540px; display: none; float: left; border-collapse: collapse;' border='1'><tbody>";
         var tfrom= "<tr><td style='width: 140px; font-size:14px;' >FROM:</td><td style='width: 400px; font-size: 14px;'>" + lfrom "</td></tr>";
         var tfaddress= "<tr><td style='width: 140px; font-size:14px;'>ADDRESS:</td><td style='width: 400px; font-size: 14px;'>" + lfaddress + "</td></tr>";
         var tfcontactno= "<tr><td style='width: 140px; font-size:14px;'>CONTACT NO:</td><td style='width: 400px; font-size: 14px;'>" + lfcontactno + "</td> </tr>";
         var note= "<tr style='border: none; height: 20px;'> <td style='border: none; text-align: center; height: 20px; font-size: 18px; padding-top:10px; padding-bottom:10px;' colspan='2'><strong>NOTE HERE</strong></td> </tr>";
         var tto= "<tr><td style='width: 140px; font-size:14px;'>TO:</td> <td style='width: 400px; font-size: 14px;'>" + lto + "</td> </tr>";
         var ttaddress= "<tr><td style='width: 140px; font-size:14px;'>ADDRESS:</td> <td style='width: 400px; font-size: 14px;'>" + ltaddress +  "<td> </tr>";
         var tbrgy= "<tr><td style='width: 140px; font-size:14px;'>BARANGAY:</td><td style='width: 400px; font-size: 14px;'>" + lbrgy + "</td></tr>";
         var tcity= "<tr><td style='width: 140px; font-size:14px;'>CITY &amp; PROVINCE:</td> <td style='width: 400px; font-size: 14px;'>" + lcity + "," + lprovince + "</td></tr>";
         var ttcontactno = "<tr><td style='width: 140px; font-size:14px;'>CONTACT NO:</td><td style='width: 400px; font-size: 14px;'>" + ltcontactno + "</td></tr>";
         var tproduct= "<tr class='page-break'><td style='width: 140px; font-size:14px;'>PRODUCT &amp; PRICE</td><td style='width: 400px; font-size: 14px;'>" + lproduct + "-" + lprice + "</td></tr>";             
        var ntable_c= "</tbody></table>";

        $("#printWayBill").append(ntable_o);
        $("#printWayBill").append(tfrom);
        $("#printWayBill").append(tfaddress);
        $("#printWayBill").append(tfcontactno);
        $("#printWayBill").append(note);
        $("#printWayBill").append(tto);
        $("#printWayBill").append(ttaddress);
        $("#printWayBill").append(tbrgy);
        $("#printWayBill").append(tcity);
        $("#printWayBill").append(ttcontactno);
        $("#printWayBill").append(tproduct);
        $("#printWayBill").append(ntable_c);

        ++j;
    }

    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use just **one** `append` and concatenate all variables:

```
$("#printWayBill").append(ntable_o+tfrom+tfaddress+tfcontactno+note+tto+ttaddress+tbrgy+tcity+ttcontactno+tproduct+ntable_c);
```

Comment: i actually did that , but its not appending at all, it seems there's an error.

Comment: it has no error on console, but nothing happens when i tried it.

Comment: my bad, i forgot to remove display:none on table :D

Answer (score -1):

From screenshot it is clear that **tr** are appending outside the table "PrintWayBillTable1".

You can do as following:

```
var ntable_o= "<table id='printWayBillTable" + j + "'"  +  " style='width: 540px; display: none; float: left; border-collapse: collapse;' border='1'><tbody>";
ntable_o += "<tr><td style='width: 140px; font-size:14px;' >FROM:</td><td style='width: 400px; font-size: 14px;'>" + lfrom "</td></tr>";
ntable_o += "<tr><td style='width: 140px; font-size:14px;'>ADDRESS:</td><td style='width: 400px; font-size: 14px;'>" + lfaddress + "</td></tr>";
ntable_o += "<tr><td style='width: 140px; font-size:14px;'>CONTACT NO:</td><td style='width: 400px; font-size: 14px;'>" + lfcontactno + "</td> </tr>";
ntable_o += "<tr style='border: none; height: 20px;'> <td style='border: none; text-align: center; height: 20px; font-size: 18px; padding-top:10px; padding-bottom:10px;' colspan='2'><strong>NOTE HERE</strong></td> </tr>";
ntable_o += "<tr><td style='width: 140px; font-size:14px;'>TO:</td> <td style='width: 400px; font-size: 14px;'>" + lto + "</td> </tr>";
ntable_o += "<tr><td style='width: 140px; font-size:14px;'>ADDRESS:</td> <td style='width: 400px; font-size: 14px;'>" + ltaddress +  "<td> </tr>";
ntable_o += "<tr><td style='width: 140px; font-size:14px;'>BARANGAY:</td><td style='width: 400px; font-size: 14px;'>" + lbrgy + "</td></tr>";
ntable_o += "<tr><td style='width: 140px; font-size:14px;'>CITY &amp; PROVINCE:</td> <td style='width: 400px; font-size: 14px;'>" + lcity + "," + lprovince + "</td></tr>";
ntable_o += "<tr><td style='width: 140px; font-size:14px;'>CONTACT NO:</td><td style='width: 400px; font-size: 14px;'>" + ltcontactno + "</td></tr>";
ntable_o += "<tr class='page-break'><td style='width: 140px; font-size:14px;'>PRODUCT &amp; PRICE</td><td style='width: 400px; font-size: 14px;'>" + lproduct + "-" + lprice + "</td></tr>";             
ntable_o += "</tbody></table>";
$("#printWayBill").append(ntable_o);
```

I think **ntable_o**, means single name is sufficient instead of separate names.

Answer (score -1):

Only one minor issue is in your code. You added a condition **if (i > 2)**. it will skip your first 3 rows. because  **i index** in **each(function (i, el) ** function returning the index starting from 0. So you should change your condition.

Because you are querying **TR** and it will return all tr of your table. whether it is header **TR** or body **TR**